# What taxes does Iraq impose on US citizens?

Tags: taxes, working

I'd like to know what taxes Iraq now imposes on US citizens working there. The last time I was there were none but a friend of mine who has a family member there told me Iraq charges taxes on US contractors -- but I'd like to verify that along with the effective tax rate.

Note: This question is nearly identical to the one I asked about Afghanistan. I think this is useful for those might have a choice about which country to work in.

Comment: The points relating to your other question apply here, too: those working for foreign governments and international organizations won't normally be taxed at all.  Employees of private companies working on government contract may or may not enjoy similar tax status depending on various circumstances.